# Распаковать архив zstd напрямую в базу mySQL

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Успешно распаковываю архивы БД *.gz и сразу направляю SQL команды в mySQL таким способом:

```
gunzip < /backup/mydatabase.sql.gz | mysql -uroot mydatabase;
```

Как тоже самое сделать для архиватора zstd?
Такой способ не работает:

```
zstd -d < /backup/mydatabase.sql.zst | mysql -uroot mydatabase;
```

Comment: Что именно не работает? Какие сообщения об ошибках? Что будет, если к `zstd` добавить опцию `--stdout`?

Comment: `zstd -dс ...` ... и, кстати, не верю, что способ из вопроса «не работает»...

Comment: Fat-Zer, вы правы, способ из вопроса работает)) видать, я вчера полусонный какой-то символ пропустил. Если не трудно подскажите, как в данном случае интерпретируется вертикальная черта linux-ом и почему используется она, а не знак направления потока ">"?